# traversing object in javascript looking for nested attribute and returning found object

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to write a function which checks if a keyword is contained in an object atrribute array. If the keyword is found in that array, it should return that object.

I tried the code below, but it doesn't work. I hope there is someone smart who can tell me what I have done wrong in this code :)

My goal is that function: `Projects.detectProjectByKeyword("brumi")` returns `ImageObjects.DE.brumi`

Or maybe there is an easier method to achieve the goal? I would very much appreciate any help, as I've been stuck here for more than a week :(

```
var ImageObjects = function() {
  var DE = {
      brumi : {
        name:"Brummi-Werk",
        keywords: ["brumi","auto", "LKWs", "lkws","lkw-werkstatt","die Brummis"]
    },
      medien : {
        name: "medien",
        keywords:["vier","nummer vier", "springer", "neue medien", "neue medien ag", "die neue medien ag"]
    },
      mautmaxe : {
        name: "mau",
        keywords:["fünf","nummer fünf", "mautmaxe", "maut", "currywust", "currywurst stand"]
      }
  };

  return {
    DE: DE
  }

}();

 function searchObj(obj, query) {
    var data ='';
    for (var property in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if (typeof obj[property] === "object") {
         data = searchObj(obj[property], query);
          if(data !='') return data;
        }
        else {
          if (obj["keywords"].indexOf(query) >= 0) {
            return  obj;
          }
          else {
              return null;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return data;
  }

var Projects = function() {

    function detectProjectByKeyword(project) {

        var foundObject = null;

        for (var x in ImageObjects.DE){
            if ((searchObj(ImageObjects.DE[x], project))!=null){
                foundObject = searchObj(ImageObjects.DE[x], project)
            }

        }
        return foundObject;

    }

  return {
    detectProjectByKeyword: detectProjectByKeyword
  }
}();
```

Comment: You might want to check my answer. If you want to learn modern JavaScript, it should be the way to go ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure never changes, IE; `ImageObjects.LANGUAGE.project.keywords`, this will suffice:

```
function detectProjectByKeyword(keyword, obj, language) {
  for(var a in obj[language]) {
    if(obj[language].hasOwnProperty(a)) {
      if(obj[language][a].keywords.indexOf(keyword) >= 0) return obj[language][a]
    }
  }
}

console.log(detectProjectByKeyword('brumi', ImageObjects, 'DE'));
console.log(detectProjectByKeyword('lkws', ImageObjects, 'DE'));
console.log(detectProjectByKeyword('mautmaxe', ImageObjects, 'DE'));
```

here's a sample: https://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/o2a01p6h/

Comment: Instead of your nested `if` statements you can do `if(condition && condition)`

Comment: @mattgreen true, but it'll fit on the SO screen this way

Comment: Noooo, you provide solutions based on this?? :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer hehe no, but that would be funny wouldn't it

Answer (score 1):

I've taken the liberty of changing your data structure slightly, but if I correctly understand what you're trying to do, then I'd expect something like the following to work:

```js
var ImageObjects =  {
  DE: {
      brumi : {
        name:                   "Brummi-Werk",
        keywords:               [
                                "brumi","auto", "LKWs", "lkws","lkw-werkstatt","die Brummis"
                                ]
    },
      medien : {
        name:                   "medien",
        keywords:               [
                                "vier","nummer vier", "springer", "neue medien", "neue medien ag", "die neue medien ag", 
                                /* added to demonstrate retrieving projects using a keyword shared across projects */, "brumi" 
                                ]
    },
      mautmaxe : {
        name:                   "mau",
        keywords:               [
                                "fünf","nummer fünf", "mautmaxe", "maut", "currywust", "currywurst stand"
                                ]
      }
  }
};

// Returns an array containing all projects with the keyword
// If only one project has a keyword, a one-element array will be returned
function findAllProjectsByKeyword(keyword) {
  var results = [];
  for (var country in ImageObjects) {
    for (var project in ImageObjects[country]) {
      var projectKeywords = ImageObjects[country][project].keywords;
      if ( projectKeywords && projectKeywords.indexOf(keyword) != -1 ) {
        results.push(ImageObjects[country][project]);
      }
    }
  }
  return results;
}

// Returns a single project with keyword
// If multiple projects have a keyword, only one will be returned
// The one that is returned may vary even for the same data, because the order
// of for-in loop enumeration may vary across implementations/runs
function findProjectByKeyword(keyword) {
  for (var country in ImageObjects) {
    for (var project in ImageObjects[country]) {
      var projectKeywords = ImageObjects[country][project].keywords;
      if ( projectKeywords && projectKeywords.indexOf(keyword) != -1 ) {
        return ImageObjects[country][project];
      }
    }
  }
}

// Example where a keyword is shared by two projects
var brumiProjects = findAllProjectsByKeyword('brumi');
console.log(brumiProjects.length);    // <= 2
console.log(brumiProjects[0].name);   // <= Brummi-Werk
console.log(brumiProjects[1].name);   // <= medien

// Only one project is returned with findProjectByKeyword, even if multiple projects have that keyword
console.log(findProjectByKeyword('brumi').name);  // <= Brummi-Werk (could be medien), depending on how the object is enumerated 

// Example where only one project has a keyword
console.log(findAllProjectsByKeyword('vier')[0].name); // <= medien
console.log(findProjectByKeyword('vier').name);        // <= medien
```

The ImageObjects structure has three levels, country (I assume), project, and project info (name and keywords). findAllProjectsByKeyword loops through the first two levels so that it searches all projects in all countries. For each project, it searches for the keyword (passed as an argument to findAllProjectsByKeyword) in the keywords array in the project object; if the keyword is found, then Array.indexOf returns the index--otherwise, it returns -1. If the keyword is found, then the found project object is pushed into the results array. findAllProjectsByKeyword will find multiple projects given a single keyword. findProjectByKeyword uses the same approach but returns only the first project found for a given keyword.

There are other subtleties you might want to consider; for instance, Array.indexOf is case-sensitive, so if you search for keyword 'Brumi', you won't get any results.

Comment: your answer seems to be the best but I can not access brumi name findProjectsByKeyword('brumi').name undefined ;(

Comment: @AnnaK, to account for the possibility that multiple projects might share the same keyword, the function returns an array of objects rather than a single object. Since there is only one project with keyword 'brumi', the returned array has only one element--you could access its name property with findProjectsByKeyword('brumi')[0].name.

Comment: @AnnaK, You could easily modify the function to return the first found object by deleting "var results = []" and "return results" and changing "results.push(ImageObjects[country][project]);" to "return ImageObjects[country][project]". Then you could access findProjectsByKeyword('brumi').name. Note, however, that the order in which object properties are enumerated by a for-in loop is not necessarily fixed, so if there are multiple projects with the same keyword, the one returned as the "first" could vary.

Comment: Could you edit your answer please so I can see how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

What about finding objects by more than a keyword and using modern ECMA-Script 2015 and above tooling and awesomeness?

See comments on the following code snippet to get insights to understand the whole solution:

```js
var ImageObjects = {
  DE: {
    brumi: {
      name: "Brummi-Werk",
      keywords: [
        "brumi", "auto", "LKWs", "lkws", "lkw-werkstatt", "die Brummis"
      ]
    },
    medien: {
      name: "medien",
      keywords: [
        "vier", "nummer vier", "springer", "neue medien", "neue medien ag", "die neue medien ag", "mautmaxe"
      ]
    },
    mautmaxe: {
      name: "mau",
      keywords: [
        "fünf", "nummer fünf", "mautmaxe", "maut", "currywust", "currywurst stand", "springer"
      ]
    }
  }
};

// #1 Second parameter is a rest parameter. Second and any other parameter
//    will be captured as an array called "keywords"
// 
// #2 Object.keys returns own given object's properties (you don't need to
//    filter them out with x.hasOwnProperty("blah"))
//
// #3 For each property of a given language object, filter those
//    that contain the whole given keywords. The "...keywords" will
//    call Array.prototype.includes as many times as keywords you've
//    provided, and the operation will be done like using && (AND) logical
//    operator: all keywords should be present or it will be false.
//
// #4 Finally, Array.prototype.map gets the whole found property and returns
//    the object held by that property!
var findByKeywords = (language, ...keywords) =>
  Object.keys(ImageObjects[language])
  .filter(property => ImageObjects[language][property].keywords.includes(...keywords))
  .map(property => ImageObjects[language][property]);
  
var result = findByKeywords("DE", "mautmaxe", "springer");

console.log(result);
```

Further reading:

- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
- [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)